# What's the full name of `IplImage` and `CvMat` in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

There is a `IplImage` and `CvMat` in OpenCV. What are the full names of them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

IPL in `IplImage` stands for **Intel Processing Library**, which is a remnant of when OpenCV was maintained by Intel.

CV in `cvMat` stands for **Computer Vision Matrix**, which is a data structure commonly used in graphics.

`IplImage` is an old structure, which I believe is internally converted into `cv::Mat`, or just `Mat` if you're in the `cv` namespace already. Likewise, `cvMat` is converted into `Mat` as well.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html?highlight=iplimage

Comment: And in EMGU CV (C# wrapper for OpenCV), the corresponding data structure is `Image<TColor, TDepth>`.